# Apply average function to MultiIndex dataframe with external condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe (**A**) has 3 MultiIndex columns. 
Another dataframe (**B**) has the information of the *quote_date*, *expiration* and *strike*.

The goal of this task is to filter the dataframe **A** using the dataframe **B**, in order to compute the average to the price column. The final dataframe must be similar to the original one, except the averaged lines.

Dataframe (**C**) is the final result that we want.
Since this function has to be applied to a big amount of data, the for loop should not be used.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

A = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,2),  1240, 1234],\
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,2), 1250, 1235], 
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,3), 1230, 1235],
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,3), 1240, 1235],
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,4), 1240, 1235],
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,5), 1240, 1235],
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,5), 1240, 1233],
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,6), 1240, 1235]], \
         columns=['quote_date', 'expiration', 'strike', 'price']).set_index(['quote_date', 'expiration', 'strike'])

B = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2005,1,1),datetime(2005,1,5),1240]], columns=['quote_date', 'expiration', 'strike'])

C = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,2),  1240, 1234],\
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,2), 1250, 1235], 
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,3), 1230, 1235],
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,3), 1240, 1235],
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,4), 1240, 1235],
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,5), 1240, 1234],
          [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,6), 1240, 1235]], \
         columns=['quote_date', 'expiration', 'strike', 'price']).set_index(['quote_date', 'expiration', 'strike'])
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `filter`, because the only difference I can see between `A` and `C` is that `C`  is the mean of `A` grouped by the index levels: `C=A.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine `B` as "MultiIndex Only" dataframe, and then mask `A` by `B` using the `index`, followed by `groupby`. Finally, combine dataframes with and without `groupby`.

```
# create "index only" dataframe
B = B.set_index(['quote_date', 'expiration', 'strike'])

# groupby only if the index of A exists in B
C = A.loc[A.index.isin(B.index)].groupby(level=[0,1,2]).mean()

# combine dataframes with/without groupby (and sort it if needed)
C = A.loc[~A.index.isin(B.index)].append(C).sort_index(level=[0,1,2])

>>> C
                               price
quote_date expiration strike       
2005-01-01 2005-01-02 1240     1234
                      1250     1235
           2005-01-03 1230     1235
                      1240     1235
           2005-01-04 1240     1235
           2005-01-05 1240     1234
           2005-01-06 1240     1235
```

Hope this helps.